# Extract text from captcha image with python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Hello i am trying to learn python
Currently i want to extract text from images like captcha.
But i tried ocr-pytesseract and 1 more which i dont remember name.
When i try to extract text from image 1 it works fine but when i want to extract text from image it gives me nothing. Any advice ? Thank you!
And here is my code.

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

path_to_image = 'alz.png'
img = Image.open(path_to_image)

#image to text
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

[image: image_1][image: image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) and with 100 images dataset I have achieved 60% accuracy on test data.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDFVF.png)

Comment: i will try in couple hours thank you! but since i am newbie is there any guide for it ? :)